# <script/> blocks the display

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I want to add some javascript in my web page:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="${contextPath}/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.5.2/jquery.iframe-transport.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.5.2/jquery.fileupload.min.js"></script>
```

But the content after script tags is not displayed when I tried after start tag `<body>`.
I also tried before the end of tag `</body>`, it displayed but javascript is not executed.
And Chrome does not generate any error

I use JSP 2.0:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<jsp:root
    xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:form="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"
    version="2.0">
    <jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" session="false"/>
    <jsp:output doctype-root-element="html" doctype-system="about:legacy-compat" />
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<!-- ... -->
</html>
```

**UPDATE**
It generates short tag javascript and it seems to be a problem for the browser:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"/><script type="text/javascript" src="/edalis/js/jquery.ui.widget.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.5.2/jquery.iframe-transport.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.5.2/jquery.fileupload.min.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/edalis/js/3dupload.js"/>
```

**FIXED** I found a solution to avoid auto tag closure but It is not pretty :-/

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript">/**/</script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript">/**/</script>
<script src="${contextPath}/js/jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript">/**/</script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.5.2/jquery.iframe-transport.min.js" type="text/javascript">/**/</script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-file-upload/9.5.2/jquery.fileupload.min.js" type="text/javascript">/**/</script>
<script src="${contextPath}/js/3dupload.js" type="text/javascript">/**/</script>
```

Comment: script tag should be inside head tag

Comment: Like the comment above, make sure your `<script>` are in the `<head>` and be sure to close the `</head>` and start the `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

try adding `type="text/javascript"` to your script tags, maybe JSP tries to execute them

Comment: I tried, I still have the problem. it is due to script auto closure